# Is it possible to send database query within a NSUrl request?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

i am developing iphone application which connects to a php page using     NSUrl request.The php page on the server side ,in turn,connects to the database (mysql) to perform transactions.Till now i was passing only parameters to the actual query on php page which was working fine.But when sending query from iphone end through NSUrl ,either connection fails or the query is assigned a nil value.Is there any way to send query using NSUrl or some othr method?

Comment: How are you sending the queries with NSURL? Mind posting your code?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a working server-side script that returns data in response to well-formed requests, so it's a matter of getting your `NSURLConnection` to make requests in the appropriate fashion. If you have a known-good request, you can inspect on the properties of the `NSURLRequest` object you're creating (`HTTPBody`, `URL`, etc.) and see where you're going wrong. Also pay attention to any error messages you might be receiving in your delegate methods (i.e., `connection:didFailWithError:`)